# correct way to create relationship in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

i am having a mysql table **relation** with following criteria.

```
id - auto_increment, primary
a_id - FK to test_table primary key, index present
a_parent_id - FK to test_table primary key, index present
(a_id + a_parent_id) has unique constrain

table entries example

a_id a_parent_id
1    null
2    null
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    5
6    4
```

currently, i have mapped test_table in hibernate

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String comment;
```

what is the correct way to map **relation** table in hibernate?

Comment: TBH you don't need that table at all. It seems like you want a parent-child relationship with the same type. For that you only need a `parentId` column in your `test_table` and in your code you use `@OneToOne @JoinColumn(name="parentId") private TestTable parent;`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer each node (id) can have multiple parents as well as children.
So, in relation table we would be having entries like;
1 -> null ;
2 -> null ;
3 -> 1 ;
4-> 1 ;
6 -> 4 ;
8 -> 4 ;

Comment: How do you differentiate between parents and children? Update you question with some properly formatted examples for the relation table. Also include how you expect the data to be returned

Comment: @XtremeBaumer updated, queries would be like select a_id from relation where a_parent_id=$;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specify that you can have multiple children/parents and from the looks of the example data, I chose to go with `List`s of parents/children instead of just chaining the relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test_table")
public class Test {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String comment;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Test.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "relation", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "a_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "a_parent_id") })
    private List<Test> parents;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Test.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "relation", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "a_parent_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "a_id") })
    private List<Test> children;

}
```

To find the parents, you look at the `relation` table with an SQL like

```
SELECT a_parent_id FROM relation WHERE a_id = ?
```

For the children you switch the columns like this:

```
SELECT a_id FROM relation WHERE a_parent_id = ?
```

This behavior should be represented by the `@JoinTable` annotations.

Comment: can you please explain meaning of targetEntity

Comment: `(Optional) The entity class that is the target of the association. Optional only if the collection-valued relationship property is defined using Java generics. Must be specified otherwise. Defaults to the parameterized type of the collection when defined using generics.` from [here](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/ManyToMany)

Comment: it does not allow me to add null values for a_parent_id, how can i keep FK constraint only if entry is not null

Comment: There is no need to add null values as parent/child ID because it is the same as no entry at all

Comment: i also want that (a_id + a_parent_id) should be unique in relation table. please describe how can i achieve the same.

Comment: composite primary key ensures that

Comment: didn't get how can i create composite primary index for relations table.
but was able to achieve same using @uniqueconstraint